# Oracle ordered resultset without order by clause

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

Is there a way to get "ordered" resultset from oracle table without actually using an "ORDER BY" clause?

I am working on an application that reads data from oracle table (which has no unique column) and I want to introduce some sort of resume mechanism so that in case of query failure (e.g. network error during fetch) we avoid reading rows that are fetched already.

The application is developed using oracle OCI and currently simple select queries are used.

Is there any efficient mechanism to achieve this?

Comment: IMHO if it has no unique column this is not really a table in the relational theory sense. You should add some PK and use it.

Comment: In datawarehousing, not having a primary key in a table is not unusual

Comment: No there is no way to get consistently ordered data out of a table without an `ORDER BY`. There is always `ROWID` but use it at your own risk. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm. But of course if the same row is deleted and inserted it will probably get a different rowid.

Answer (score 1):

In some very special condition you have a defined order of results without given any ORDER BY clause. However, you shoul not rely on that, Oracle may change this behaviour any time.

Maybe you can count total number of rows (read `SQL%ROWCOUNT` after executioin of the query) and check this number with received records on your client.

Answer (score 1):

As Wernfried pointed out, there is no reliable way to get ordered results without *any* `ORDER BY`.  But the question assumes that `ORDER BY` is impossible because there are no unique columns.  There are at least two workarounds to this.

**1. ROWID.**    Every Oracle row has a unique pseudo-column, `ROWID`.  The application could `ORDER BY ROWID`, store the latest `ROWID`, and then use `WHERE ROWID <= :rowid` to pick up where it left off.  Note that `ROWIDs` can change, if the table was modified or moved.

**2. ROW_NUMBER.**  Another option is to sort all the data and keep track of the duplicates.  If two rows are exactly the same then it does not matter which of the duplicates were returned and processed.  The query and application only need to track how many of them have been processed.  Then it can later process the rest.

```
drop table test1;

create table test1(a number);
insert into test1 values(1);
insert into test1 values(1);
insert into test1 values(2);
commit;

select a ,row_number() over (order by a /*and all other columns*/) rowNumber
from test1
order by rowNumber

A  ROWNUMBER
1  1          --Am I the real #1?  It doesn't matter.
1  2
2  3
```

If there was a failure after the first row, adding the predicate `where rownumber > :last_rownumber_processed` will get the rest of the rows.  The second query may return the "first" 1 instead of the "second" 1, but the application won't care.  As with the first workaround, this will fail if the data changes between runs.

Either way, the query must pay for sorting:

```
----------------------------
| Id  | Operation          |
----------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |
|   1 |  WINDOW SORT       |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL|
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

**case 1:**

In order to achieve a simple resume mechanism the only simple way is to use RowID.

```
select t?.rowid, t1.*, t2.*, t3.* 
 from table1 t1, 
      table2 t2,
      table3 t3
where t1.? = t2.?
  and t2.? = t3.?
  and t?.rowid > :rowidProcessedPriorNetworkFailure
 order by t?.rowid
```

Reason for t?.rowid is because you have to choose the leaf table.

in the following case you should choose t3 as t?.
T2 - T1 : one T2 record may have one or more T1 records
T1 - T3 : one T1 record may have one or more T3 records

But keep in mind that RowID's will change whenever Oracle maintains the underlying physical structure (ie. defragmantation, Regorganization, Move of table to a new datafile)

**case 2:**

if it is a join, select the leaf table. 
Select a column that has the most distinct values. Order by that column. and whenever you have to resume, reverse operations done with the last value on hand.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -2):

I have used the following query to get ordered output without using "order by" words. Here, I want to sort empno without using order by clause.

Query:

```
Select empno, sal, deptno, max(sal) over(partition by empno) from emp;
```

However you can exclude any columns except empno and `max()` analytical function.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: No. Without an `Order By`, there is no guarantee your result will be in any particular order.

Comment: Are you trying to answer or ask something?

Comment: Hi Nick, if you run the explain plan for the query, the "Option" column will have "Sort". Please let me know if you are getting different result.